# Insert data into a SQLite DB using LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, windows-runtime

I need to take some text fields and insert that data into a SQLite DB using LINQ to SQL. This is what I have so far:

```cs
var ordersDB = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(orderPath);

Orders ord = new Orders();

ord.custNum = tblCustomerNumber.Text;
ord.itemNum = tbxEnterItem.Text;
ord.itemQty = tbxQty.Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some pretty good examples here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/236918/Using-SQLite-embedded-database-with-entity-framewo
http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/articles/tutorial_linq.html
http://vijayt.com/Post/Using-SQLite-database-in-NET-with-LINQ-to-SQL-

You might look into using [EntityFramework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/ef), which makes things very easy.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it working:

```
var ordersDB = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(orderPath);

Orders ord = new Orders();


ord.custNum = tblCustomerNumber.Text;
ord.itemNum = tbxEnterItem.Text;
ord.itemQty = tbxQty.Text;
ord.itemDesc = tblOrderItemDesc.Text;
ord.itemCost = tblOrderItemCost.Text;
ord.orderDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();


ordersDB.BeginTransaction();
ordersDB.Insert(ord);
ordersDB.Commit();

ordersDB.Dispose();
ordersDB.Close();
```